# Grails start application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, grails

Every time i start grails applications- it has this error message and i don't know why?

| Error 2014-03-06 19:30:55,494 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: could not resolve property: location of: tutor.com.Tutor; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: location of: tutor.com.Tutor
Message: could not resolve property: location of: tutor.com.Tutor; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: location of: tutor.com.Tutor

This is my tutor.com.Tutor domain:

```
package tutor.com

class Tutor {

    String description
    String qualifications
    String experience
    double feedback
    int rate

    User user

    static hasMany = [ subjects: Subject ]

    static mapping={
        description(sqlType: 'text')
    }

    static constraints = {
        feedback(nullable:true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create some Tutors objects in Bootstrap.groovy?

Comment: is your package correct?

Answer (score 1):

There must be something in your `Bootstrap` or some other initializing code to call the missing `tutor.location` property